# Pack Strings in WPF User Control Library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I had created a User Control in my main Project Originally. I have now created a new Project that uses the WPF User Control Library Template and moved my control there.

The issue I am having, is my control uses images as the content for buttons. I have moved the images along with the controls into the new project, but I cannot get the Pack URIs to work. The Control and the images both reside in the same folder of the project called `MyControl` an the new Project name is `MyControls`.

I have tried:

```
<Button Name="Button1" ToolTip="Button1" Click="Button1Action">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyControl/image1.png" />
</Button>
```

and

```
<Button Name="Button1" ToolTip="Button1" Click="Button1Action">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,MyControls;/MyControl/image1.png" />
</Button>
```

I also tried adding the images to the `Resources.resx` file, then in the Code Behind converting that to a `BitmapSource`, creating an Image control, setting its source to the `BitmapSource`, and then setting the `Button.Content` to the `Image`. I assume that since the png has a transparent background, it was messed up in the process, it was displayed with a black background using this method.

The Build Action for the Image in the project is set to `Resource`, so I assume I am just missing the correct Pack string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second pack uri was close, but you missed one word (and a slash)! It should be

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyControls;component/MyControl/image1.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I wrongly assumed that the example in [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) was just showing the file in a folder called component. Looking back if I had read that page closer, I would have saved myself a couple hours.

Comment: Glad I could help. Pack URI's are definitely a strange beast, and I've never really understood why the `component` needs to be there.